# How to do IP-based API rate limitation in node.js cluster mode?

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, rate-limiting

I am running a node.js/express/socket.io app in cluster mode. 
I run an external server for the masterprocess and internal servers for the workers as in the following code.

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {

var workers = [];

var spawn = function(i) {
    workers[i] = cluster.fork();

    // Optional: Restart worker on exit
    workers[i].on('exit', function(code, signal) {
        console.log('Process exited! respawning worker no: ', i);
        spawn(i);
    });
  };

  // Spawn workers.
for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
    spawn(i);
}


var worker_index = function(ip, len) {
    return farmhash.fingerprint32(ip) % len; // Farmhash is the fastest and works with IPv6, too
};

// Create the outside facing server listening on our port.
var server = net.createServer({ pauseOnConnect: true }, function(connection) {

  //!!!! the connection.remoteAddress causes issues with reverse proxy, however here not important as socket.io is used only for a global signalling to all clients
  // console.log(connection.remoteAddress);
    var worker = workers[worker_index(connection.remoteAddress, numCPUs)];
    worker.send('sticky-session:connection', connection);
}).listen(port);

console.log('***************************************');
console.log('listening EXTERNALLY http://localhost:' + port);
console.log("This system has " + numCPUs + " virtual or real CPUs");
console.log('***************************************');
connection.remoteAddress // --> this is 127.0.0.1

} else {

// all worker processes enter the app from server.js
require("./server.js");
}
```

And then in server.js, which is being started up according to the number of cores available on the system.

```
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');
...
app.enable("trust proxy"); // only if you're behind a reverse proxy (Heroku, Bluemix, AWS ELB, Nginx, etc)
...
app.use('/api/', apiLimiter); // --> this does not work as the real IP is not available
...

//startup the HTTP server
 server.listen(0, 'localhost', function(err) {
     console.log('***************************************');
console.log('***************************************');
  console.log('listening INTERNALLY http://localhost:0');
console.log('***************************************');


});
```

With this code, the API limit (express-rate-limit) from node.js does not work. I suspect it is because the IP is always the same on the internal server (127.0.0.1, localhost).

After creating the http server, I can get the real IP with the following command:

```
req.headers['x-real-ip'] ||  req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

But this does not work before the http server has been created but I need this to enable the API limiter.

Somehow, I need to pass along the IP-address from the external server which seems is a TCP server. 
Is there a way to capture the real IP at the very beginning before creating the http server?

Comment: [rate-limiter-flexible works with Cluster](https://github.com/animir/node-rate-limiter-flexible/wiki/Cluster) without any 3rd party store.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for